# python scipy.fft huge y scale of Fast Fourier Transform

Tags: python, fft

I have a working python script for Fast Fourier Transform (fft) signal which plots the graph and fft correctly, I am fetching data from postgre so I ommited that code.
And due to limit of paste i pasted shorter version of signal, but the signal is preatty much the similar on longer timeframe.

The x scale of fft is fine, but what i get is a large y scale which i do not understand.

I have an fft processed by machine directly that looks correct and i have another measurement done by hand held machine. The ffts look almost identical on x scale and relative sizes on y scale, but the actual calculated y scale differ a lot.

[data](https://pastebin.com/QnPHbmYN)

[plot from python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BV99w.png)

[from device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2npw7.jpg)

In script data_step is in micro second between two timestamps.
The n and datastep cant be wrong since the x axis is fine.
From the data i get:

```
Min of signal(value_points_sensor1): -0.057881687

Max of signal: 0.07810274

Max of fft y: 5522.93
```

Shouldnt the  size  of fft be similar to size of amplitude of signal? Also arent the unit of amplitude on fft and signal on y axis the same?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.fft import rfft, rfftfreq, irfft
import numpy as np

figure, axis = plt.subplots(2, 1)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=1)
    
time_points_sensor1 = np.array(row[4])
value_points_sensor1 = np.array(row[3])
    
axis[0].plot(time_points_sensor1, value_points_sensor1)

   
n  = len(row[2])
data_step = (abs((int(row[2][-2] - row[2][-1]))) / 1000000)

yf = rfft(value_points_sensor1)
xf = rfftfreq(n,data_step)

axis[1].plot(xf,abs(yf))
    
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of rfft is proportional both to the magnitude of the data and the number of points.  So you should expect the values in `yf` to be large.

Compare:

```
# One cycle of a cosine curve
x = rfft(np.cos(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 1000)))
max(abs(x))
500.2493021844711

# Two cycles of a cosine curve, again 1000 points per cycle
x = rfft(np.cos(np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, 2000)))
max(abs(x))
1000.2484171710441
```

Comment: Thank you, it is clear now i had to divide it with lenght of signal

Answer (score 0):

Please see the description below of the input parameter **norm** of [scipy.fft.rfft](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fft.rfft.html#scipy.fft.rfft). By default the normalization is done on the [irfft](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fft.irfft.html#scipy.fft.irfft). However you can choose ortho to apply normalization on both rfft and irfft

**[norm](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fft.fft.html#scipy.fft.fft){“backward”, “ortho”, “forward”}, optional
Normalization mode. Default is “backward”, meaning no normalization on the forward transforms and scaling by 1/n on the ifft. “forward” instead applies the 1/n factor on the forward tranform. For norm="ortho", both directions are scaled by 1/sqrt(n).**